# Cakephp 3.x Crud plugin beforeFind event not available

Tags: rest, api, cakephp, listener, cakephp-3.0

I have a Cakephp 3.x API using CRUD plugin.
This is my crud configuration:

```
$this->loadComponent('Crud.Crud', [
            'actions' => [
                'Crud.Index',
                'Crud.View',
                'Crud.Add',
                'Crud.Edit',
                'Crud.Delete'
            ],
            'listeners' => [
                'Crud.Api',
                'Crud.ApiPagination',
                'Crud.ApiQueryLog'
            ]
        ]);
```

In my controller when I call this->Crud->implementedEvents() it returns beforeFilter startuperxot beforePaginate only

```
public function index(){
    $this->Crud->implementedEvents(); //returns beforeFilter startuperxot beforePaginate
    $this->Crud->on('beforeFind', function(\Cake\Event\Event $event) {
        if(isset($this->request->query['state'])){
            $event->getSubject()->query->where(['state =' => $this->request->query['state']]);
        }
    });
    return $this->Crud->execute();
}
```

How can I enable beforeFind listener? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `beforePaginate` on index

https://crud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/actions/index.html#crud-beforepaginate